# Setting up a SMS Registration System with AWS Pinpoint & Lambda

Tags: node.js, ajax, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-pinpoint

I'm attempting to setup an SMS Registration System with AWS Pinpoint, Lambda, API Gateway, and SNS. However, whenever I'm attempting to process the data using ajax with their example, it gives an error everytime.

I've followed the guide here to setup the entire system: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/tutorials-two-way-sms.html

I've tested both of the Lambda functions in AWS and they work perfectly. However, I cannot see an API request being sent when I send the data over my form.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Meta tags required by Bootstrap -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="SMSFormHandler.js"></script>
  <title>SMS Registration Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Register for SMS Alerts</h1>
        <p>Enter your phone number below to sign up for PromotionName messages from ExampleCorp.</p>
        <p>We don't share your contact information with anyone else. For more information, see our <a href="http://example.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a>.</p>
        <p>ExampleCorp alerts are only available to recipients in the United States.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName" class="font-weight-bold">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Your first name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName" class="font-weight-bold">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Your last name" required>
          </div>
          <label for="areaCode" class="font-weight-bold">Phone number</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="h3">(&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="areaCode" placeholder="Area code" required>
            <span class="h3">&nbsp;)&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone1" placeholder="555" required>
            <span class="h3">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone2" placeholder="0199" required>
          </div>
          <div id="form-response"></div>
          <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <small class="text-muted">Copyright © 2019, ExampleCorp or its affiliates.</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And the Javascript (I've redacted the API):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Handle form submission.
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {

    var firstName = $("#firstName").val(),
        lastName = $("#lastName").val(),
        source = window.location.pathname,
        optTimestamp = undefined,
        utcSeconds = Date.now() / 1000,
        timestamp = new Date(0),
        phone = $("#areaCode").val()
              + $("#phone1").val()
              + $("#phone2").val();

    e.preventDefault();

    if (firstName == "") {
      $('#form-response').html('<div class="mt-3 alert alert-info" role="alert">Please enter your first name.</div>');
    } else if (lastName == "") {
      $('#form-response').html('<div class="mt-3 alert alert-info" role="alert">Please enter your last name.</div>');
    } else if (phone.match(/[^0-9]/gi)) {
      $('#form-response').html('<div class="mt-3 alert alert-info" role="alert">Your phone number contains invalid characters. Please check the phone number that you supplied.</div>');
    } else if (phone.length < 10) {
      $('#form-response').html('<div class="mt-3 alert alert-info" role="alert">Please enter your phone number.</div>');
    } else if (phone.length > 10) {
      $('#form-response').html('<div class="mt-3 alert alert-info" role="alert">Your phone number contains too many digits. Please check the phone number that you supplied.</div>');
    } else {
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#submit').html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Saving your preferences</button>');

      timestamp.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);

      var data = JSON.stringify({
        'destinationNumber': phone,
        'firstName': firstName,
        'lastName': lastName,
        'source': source,
      });

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://############.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/register',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data,
        success: function(res) {
          $('#form-response').html('<div class="mt-3 alert alert-success" role="alert"><p>Congratulations! You&apos;ve successfully registered for SMS Alerts from ExampleCorp.</p><p>We just sent you a message. Follow the instructions in the message to confirm your subscription. We won&apos;t send any additional messages until we receive your confirmation.</p><p>If you decide you don&apos;t want to receive any additional messages from us, just reply to one of our messages with the keyword STOP.</p></div>');
          $('#submit').prop('hidden', true);
          $('#unsubAll').prop('hidden', true);
          $('#submit').text('Preferences saved!');
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
          $('#form-response').html('<div class="mt-3 alert alert-danger" role="alert">An error occurred. Please try again later.</div>');
          $('#submit').text('Save preferences');
          $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

AWS Lambda Function:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var pinpoint = new AWS.Pinpoint({region: process.env.region}); 

// Make sure the SMS channel is enabled for the projectId that you specify.
// See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-sms-setup.html
var projectId = process.env.projectId;

// You need a dedicated long code in order to use two-way SMS. 
// See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-voice-manage.html#channels-voice-manage-request-phone-numbers
var originationNumber = process.env.originationNumber;

// This message is spread across multiple lines for improved readability.
var message = "ExampleCorp: Reply YES to confirm your subscription. 2 msgs per "
            + "month. No purchase req'd. Msg&data rates may apply. Terms: "
            + "example.com/terms-sms";

var messageType = "TRANSACTIONAL";

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log('Received event:', event);
  validateNumber(event);
};

function validateNumber (event) {
  var destinationNumber = event.destinationNumber;
  if (destinationNumber.length == 10) {
    destinationNumber = "+1" + destinationNumber;
  }
  var params = {
    NumberValidateRequest: {
      IsoCountryCode: 'US',
      PhoneNumber: destinationNumber
    }
  };
  pinpoint.phoneNumberValidate(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
    }
    else {
      console.log(data);
      //return data;
      if (data['NumberValidateResponse']['PhoneTypeCode'] == 0) {
        createEndpoint(data, event.firstName, event.lastName, event.source);
      } else {
        console.log("Received a phone number that isn't capable of receiving "
                   +"SMS messages. No endpoint created.");
      }
    }
  });
}

function createEndpoint(data, firstName, lastName, source) {
  var destinationNumber = data['NumberValidateResponse']['CleansedPhoneNumberE164'];
  var endpointId = data['NumberValidateResponse']['CleansedPhoneNumberE164'].substring(1);

  var params = {
    ApplicationId: projectId,
    // The Endpoint ID is equal to the cleansed phone number minus the leading
    // plus sign. This makes it easier to easily update the endpoint later.
    EndpointId: endpointId,
    EndpointRequest: {
      ChannelType: 'SMS',
      Address: destinationNumber,
      // OptOut is set to ALL (that is, endpoint is opted out of all messages)
      // because the recipient hasn't confirmed their subscription at this
      // point. When they confirm, a different Lambda function changes this 
      // value to NONE (not opted out).
      OptOut: 'ALL',
      Location: {
        PostalCode:data['NumberValidateResponse']['ZipCode'],
        City:data['NumberValidateResponse']['City'],
        Country:data['NumberValidateResponse']['CountryCodeIso2'],
      },
      Demographic: {
        Timezone:data['NumberValidateResponse']['Timezone']
      },
      Attributes: {
        Source: [
          source
        ]
      },
      User: {
        UserAttributes: {
          FirstName: [
            firstName
          ],
          LastName: [
            lastName
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  };
  pinpoint.updateEndpoint(params, function(err,data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
    }
    else {
      console.log(data);
      //return data;
      sendConfirmation(destinationNumber);
    }
  });
}

function sendConfirmation(destinationNumber) {
  var params = {
    ApplicationId: projectId,
    MessageRequest: {
      Addresses: {
        [destinationNumber]: {
          ChannelType: 'SMS'
        }
      },
      MessageConfiguration: {
        SMSMessage: {
          Body: message,
          MessageType: messageType,
          OriginationNumber: originationNumber
        }
      }
    }
  };

  pinpoint.sendMessages(params, function(err, data) {
    // If something goes wrong, print an error message.
    if(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    // Otherwise, show the unique ID for the message.
    } else {
      console.log("Message sent! " 
          + data['MessageResponse']['Result'][destinationNumber]['StatusMessage']);
    }
  });
}
```

Environment variables are set for originationNumber, projectId, and region.

I'm expecting it to send a request to the REST API, which triggers the Lambda function to send an SMS message. However, it doesn't end up sending the request. I've also tried general REST API testing with Postman, which then gives me errors in the Lambda function. I tested using a REST API testing website, and it says it is reporting HTTP 0 error. And it mentions to make sure I have CORS enabled, and I have it enabled on my API already.

Please let me know if you have any ideas!

Thanks.

Comment: "I've also tried general REST API testing with Postman, which then gives me errors in the Lambda function" - what kind of error?

Comment: @AssaelAzran Here's a few different examples of errors I'm receiving:
https://i.imgur.com/ibWThRP.png
https://i.imgur.com/qLOAeDw.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, CORS on my REST API was causing issues. So I just removed it.

Now, my API was finally accepting requests. However, the test AWS function was no longer working. I ended up adding the following try-catch statement to parse JSON data if it doesn't give an error:

```
  try {
    event = JSON.parse(event.body);
  } catch (e) {
    event = event.body;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer releies on the assumption that you configured you API Gateway as **Lambda Proxy Integration**.
Base on your error examples i can see
there is a problem inside **validateNumber** function.
Your data is inside event.body and not inside event.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html

Change :

```
var destinationNumber = event.destinationNumber
```

To:

```
const body = JSON.parse(event.body)
var destinationNumber = body.destinationNumber
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for responding! After adding that into my code, I now the receive the following error after testing: https://i.imgur.com/FJWGLGp.png

Comment: Please add `console.log(event.destinationNumber)` at the beginning of your lambda. i want to see the error message.

Comment: Add it inside your handler

Comment: Here's what it output now:
https://pastebin.com/tUsCsG5e

That's what I see now. I blanked out the number with X's